# Is it possible to use SDL's audio library without the rest of SDL?

Tags: sdl

With the release of SDL 2.0, SDL's audio library is starting to look very promising. And, other than the outdated OpenAL, it seems to be the only half-decent free option available for cross-platform audio.

However, I don't currently use SDL for any other purpose. I use GLFW for my window/OpenGL management, and have no desire to switch.

Is it possible to just use the audio portion of SDL as a simple library without committing to use of the entire SDL framework? Do the SDL audio APIs make assumptions about the rest of SDL being initialized and available?

Comment: "outdated OpenAL"...like [OpenAL SI](http://web.archive.org/web/20130729040534/http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/default.aspx)?  Or are you talking about [OpenAL Soft](http://kcat.strangesoft.net/openal.html)?

Comment: The first one, I suppose. The official Creative Labs version. The last public OpenAL release was back in 2005.

Answer (score 0):

When calling SDL_Init(), Pass SDL_INIT_AUDIO only.

http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Init

Comment: Not sure if you answer addresses the original question. 

It's the same one I have. What we're basically asking, is how can we use an SDL subsystem, without actually having to compile the subsystems we don't use.

Initialising the subsystem is simple enough, but it doesn't feel like an optimal solution.